# android some headers not accessible from getHeaderFields

Tags: android

I'm working on an app that requires http headers to store cookies. For some reason the original headers are

```
GET /app?service=page/UserWebPrint HTTP/1.1
Host:xxxyyy
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: cookievalue1;cookievalue2
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
X-Client-Data: CKW2yQEIxLbJAQj9lcoBCJKXygE=

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 05 Mar 2016 19:08:55 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

but output of :

```
Map<String, List<String>> headerFields1 = conn2.getHeaderFields()
System.out.println(headerFields1);
```

is:

```
{Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store], Content-Type=[text/html; charset=utf-8], Date=[Sat, 05 Mar 2016 19:17:52 GMT], Expires=[Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT], Pragma=[no-cache], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], X-Frame-Options=[SAMEORIGIN]}
```

How can I access the cookies?

Comment: There are no cookie headers in your sample HTTP response. Hence, there will be no cookie headers in the parsed HTTP response.

Comment: Sir, the response has Cookie field, it is just that getHeaderFields() returns headers from HTTP 200 OK onwards

Comment: "Sir, the response has Cookie field" -- not according to either your original or edited question. Your *request* has a `Cookie` header. Your response does not have any headers related to cookies.

Comment: Cookie: cookievalue1;cookievalue2  this line from the post has cookies

Comment: That is the *request*. The *response* does not have cookies. You are examining the header fields of the *response*.

Comment: Sir, I think you misunderstood my question, that post above is the "response" from the server.

Comment: No, the first portion is a *request*. After the blank line is the response. See [this example in the Wikipedia page on HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Example_session).

Comment: Okay thank-you for guiding me. I didn't knew that.